# SSIS Error - The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager failed with error code 0xC0202009

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2014

I have scoured high and low for a solution but nothing has helped. To be clear, I am **not** developing a SSIS package, I am simply trying to run one that has already proven to work. This issue is server specific.

We have an ETL Job that builds a repository from a production database for reporting purposes. I built a new VM server with bigger resources to ease the burden of this process on our larger databases.

Server is Windows Server 2012R2. Running SQL Server 2014 SP2 CU05 with integration services and really not much else. This job runs through the agent on 15 minute intervals. The first few times it runs, it does actually start building some of the data in the destination database, but this error persists with every new batch that is executed, whether manually or on schedule, and after a while it just stops moving data.

Here is the base error:

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQVIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER. The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "ETL_Framework" failed with error code 0xCO202009. 
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

Said error messages before the AcquireConnection call:

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. 
>   Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Description: "Login timeout expired". 
>   Source. "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Description: "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online." 
>   Source. "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Description: "Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]. ".

One important thing to bear in mind is that both the source and destination databases are on this **same server** that the job is running from, meaning everything is localized and the domain service account is a local admin on the server and a sysadmin on SQL.

I have Named Pipes and TCP/IP protocols enabled on SQL. The service account running the job is a domain user that I have used hundreds of times on other servers setup for this same kind of work with never having a problem. I can connect via SSMS to this server from other VMs using the FQDN of the instance (i.e. SZDB.somewhere.com\SQL2014), and vice-versa.

So, open to suggestions here. There has to be something I am missing in the setup of my server.

Answer (score 0):

We found that the solution in this case was to install a default instance of SQL Server. I previously only had a named instance running. As soon as I went through SQL setup and installed the default instance (i.e. MSSQLSERVER), the error on our ETL job went away and our data warehouse continued to build without any further issues. Proved to be the solution on two other servers as well that were exhibiting the same issue.